# What is after the Ising model?

Tags: ising-model

If this model is solved in three dimensions,

**Will there be additional research on it? Like what?**

**Does this open the way to solve other models? Like what?**

Comment: There are no other models. If we solve the 3D Ising model, all condensed matter physicists will be given early retirement.

Comment: @RubenVerresen what about the SYK model, I've read that this model will play an important role in black holes, string theory, and quantum information.

Comment: could I know why is question has been closed?

Comment: Although it would be nice to have a solution of the 3d Ising model, it is by no means necessary to analyze its properties in detail: one knows a lot about this model, even rigorously. And an exact solution would only provide limited informations and thus would not prevent further research on this topic.

Comment: For instance in 2d, where an exact solution is available, this has by no means slowed down the research on this model, simply because an exact solution only gives you (very) partial information. In the 2d model, one is able to compute the free energy and (in principle) correlation functions and a handful of other derived quantities.

Comment: So, for instance, one cannot include a magnetic field, one cannot study the model with fixed magnetization, one cannot consider finite systems with a nontrivial geometry/boundary conditions, etc. But all this can be (and has been!) studied with no recourse to the exact solution.

Comment: @YvanVelenik But I've read that ''solving Ising's model in three dimensions would be very great, and the least he can be offered is a Nobel Prize''.

Comment: It would be a remarkable mathematical feat. I strongly doubt that this would lead to a Nobel prize, however, as the solution itself (that is, the exact expressions obtained) would probably not lead to conceptual breakthroughs. Of course, the methods used to obtain such a solution (if at all possible) would very likely be revolutionary in the theory of integrable systems.